# How to automate data consumption from a file present in website to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to automate data consumption from any file present in [this website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/the-uk-sanctions-list) into Azure Snowflake.

We have data vendors in Snowflake Marketplace, but they seem costly. So, can someone please suggest an optimal way of achieving this?

I tried manually downloading the file and loading into Snowflake, but looking for an optimal way of automating the data consuming from here

Comment: The optimal way would be a script, either snowpark or standalone to download the file and load in to Snowflake